# How to capture commandline output

Tags: command-line, capture, output

I want to run

```
"runas /user:xxxx "aspnet_regiis /i"
```

in my windows 2008 server, it failed with a quick popup window disappears right away.

How can I capture the output? or let the popup window not disappear right away until I close it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: No, it's commandline, any difference?

Comment: Run it from `cmd`, to see where your command is failing. When you have fixed that, it should present you with a password prompt.

Comment: I was running it from cmd, and it asks me for password, I typed it in, it gives me message in another window and the other window disappears in less than 1 second.

Comment: Then it must be the way `aspnet_regiis` runs. Try running it via `start runas /user:xxxx "aspnet_regiis /i`.

Comment: No, this time it opens another commandline window to prompt me to type in password, after I typed it in, it disappears even faster

Comment: All I need to do is to run this command, is there any way to run it in a windows interface instead of commandline? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved, all I need is to see the output which has some error message. I run as the cmd and get the right privilege and everything is fine.

Thanks for replying.