# how to capture the devcon.exe's output log under the the normal users?

Tags: python, windows

Now I want to capture the devcon.exe's output in the normal users permission,
[How to capture commandline output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213751/how-to-capture-commandline-output)
the guy resolve this problem just in the administator's permission,yes! I can capture the log in the adminstrator's permission,but now I need to capture the log in the normal users' permission,a quick popup window disappears right away,so I can not get the log of the devcon such as :(`P = subprocess.Popen("devcon.exe","-h",stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print P.stdout.readline()`) the python capture nothing because the devcon put the log in a popup windows process,Is there any ways to capture the log of the devcon.exe in the normal users permission?